# Should a installable trigger for 'OnFormSubmit' work in an Form add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing an Google Apps Script add-on in Google Forms. The add-on includes a button to install a Trigger. The trigger should run after Form is submitted. Within a Form Script the function is working, trigger is set and trigger runs when a form is submitted.
The same don't work in an add-on. The function to set the trigger runs. The trigger seems to be set successful (I have tested this by checking in script if the trigger is already available). However after formsubmit, no trigger is activated :(
I have checked this in the execution log as well.

Any thoughts? Should this be possible in a Form add-on?

```
function triggerSet() {
/* Set trigger onformSumbit*/
  "use strict";
  try {
    //test if trigger is already available
    var triggerAvailable = false;
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(FormApp.getActiveForm());
    triggers.forEach(function (trigger) {
      if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === "onSubmit") {
        triggerAvailable = true;
        console.log("triggerSet: already there");
      }
    });
    //if trigger = false then set new trigger
    if (triggerAvailable === false) {
      console.log("triggerSet: new");
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("onSubmit")
        .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
      console.log("triggerSet: true");
    }
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("triggerSet: " + e.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

For completeness also the onsubmit event it self.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  "use strict";
  try {
    console.log ("onSubmit!!!!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("onSubmit: " + e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Apps Script runtime version v8?  I have a Forms editor add-on that uses an On Form Submit trigger, and it is working.

Comment: I tried to replicate your code and it is working. Have you tried replicating it to another form?

Comment: @AlanWells, yes it running in V8.

Comment: @NikkoJ. Just tried it with a new test form. The same result. I have a Apps Script–managed Cloud Platform project. Would that make any difference?

Comment: If it's possible for you to revert back to DEPRECATED_ES5 then I'd try that.  V8 has had various issues that have basically made some people's code unusable. [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184664889](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184664889)